# pattern to match comma separated user stories

Tags: regex

I want to make sure entries are formatted correctly. a user story could be entered as `US12312412` or `US12312412,...,US12312415`. Any number of user stories separated by commas. Here is the regular expression I came up with: `"US[0-9](,US[0-9])*")`. Why does `(,US[0-9])*` recognize more inputs than just additional user stories with a comma in front? That portion will also accept `,,,,,,,,`. How can I write it to make sure it only accepts what i wrote above?

Comment: Use `^US[0-9]+(?:,US[0-9]+)*$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/3wuaJ4/1). Does `US[0-9](,US[0-9])*` really validate `,,,,,`? [I can't repro](https://regex101.com/r/3wuaJ4/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `"(,US[0-9])*"` does I meant

Comment: Another idea to use one group with boundary `^(?:US\d+,?\b)+$` which is not faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `[0-9]` pattern only matches one digit. To match one or more occurrences, you need to apply a `+` quantifier to it. So, to match a single `US` code you need `US[0-9]+`.

Then, you need to anchor the pattern to only match the entire string unless the method the parses the pattern does that automatically.

```
^US[0-9]+(?:,US[0-9]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3wuaJ4/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `US` - a `US` substring
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:,US[0-9]+)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `,` - a comma
  - `US[0-9]+` - `US` and 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.